# How to bind a dictionary for PreviewProvider in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

How do you bind data for the PreviewProvider when it is a dictionary and not a string? For example, this works:

```
struct Card: View {

    @Binding var name:String

    var body: some View {

        HStack{
            Text(name)
        }
    }
}

struct Card: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Card(name: Binding.constant("John"),
    }
}
```

But how would you do it if the var is a dictionary?

```
struct Card: View {

    @Binding var person: Person

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(Person.name)
            Text(Person.age)
        }
    }
}

struct Card_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    @Binding var person: Person

    static var previews: some View {
        Card( ?????? )
    }
}
```

The model would be:

```
struct Person: Codable {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do it the same way, but instead of initializing the String you would initialize the struct.

`Card(person: .constant(Person(name: "John", age: 18)))`